# How to show only coefficient section including the signif codes from summary(model) in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

This one may be very simple but I just couldn't find anywhere that shows me how to do it, maybe it's the keywords I put in.

Basically, in rmarkdown, when I input below, I will get the full output from the summary.

```
model = lm(y~x,data=xxx)
summary(model)
```

However, I'm only interested in showing the coefficients section. I've tried to use below to output the coefficients only, but the *** sign disappears (signif codes). Is there a way to output the coefficients section including the *** sign?

```
summary(model)$coefficients
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to write extra code. The `print.summary.lm` function uses the function `printCoefmat`

```
printCoefmat(summ.lm$coefficients)
            Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.03200    0.22022 22.8501 9.547e-15 ***
groupTrt    -0.37100    0.31143 -1.1913     0.249    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't know if this will be the case forever. There is a fairly strong body of opinion among R Core that this "feature" was a mistake and that significance stars are often used to mislead the statistically naive reader.

Comment: If I would like to output selective parts of a mixed effect model. How can I for example output the fixed effect section in a mixed effect model summary? And most importantly, where and what can I search to learn all of the relevant code associated with summary?
For example, I want to output summary(model.me)$fixed.effects (this obviously doesn't work...)

Comment: It’s a different question. Write up a question that includes a library call to load whatever package is being anticipated and then produce code that builds a suitable object for investigative effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` and `broom` to create a dataframe with what you want, but you would need a built-in function to add the stars. Here an option for you with an example:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
#Function for p-values
myfun <- function(pval) {
  stars = ""
  if(pval <= 0.001)
    stars = "***"
  if(pval > 0.001 & pval <= 0.01)
    stars = "**"
  if(pval > 0.01 & pval <= 0.05)
    stars = "*"
  if(pval > 0.05 & pval <= 0.1)
    stars = "."
  stars
}
#Code
mtcars %>% 
  lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, .) %>% 
  tidy() %>% 
  mutate(signif = sapply(p.value, function(x) myfun(x)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value signif
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> 
1 (Intercept)   19.7       5.25       3.76 7.65e- 4 ***   
2 wt            -5.05      0.484    -10.4  2.52e-11 ***   
3 qsec           0.929     0.265      3.51 1.50e- 3 **
```